# В чем разница между FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser(); VS FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

Tags: android, firebase

```
FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
assert user != null;
```

И что значит assert?

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
```

Comment: А откуда берётся переменная `firebaseAuth`? Если она берётся как `FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()`, то разницы не будет никакой. Конструкция `assert` тянет на отдельный вопрос.

Comment: assert: https://habrahabr.ru/post/141080/

Answer (score 0):

Разницы абсолютно никакой. Чтобы получить обьект `FirebaseAuth` нужно вызвать статический метод `getInstance()`. Соответсвенно разница между `FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();` и `FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();` лишь в том что в первом случае мы сохраняем обьект в переменную а во втором нет.

На счет **assert** - не уверен откуда вы это взяли но аналог на Java будет выглядеть следующим образом

```
if (user != null) {
            // User is signed in
            Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
        } else {
            // User is signed out
            Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
        }
```

**Assert** от англ. предпологать. Соответсвенно нам нужна эта проверка для того чтобы в дальнейшем выполнять действия над этой переменной.